# Change battery warning thresholds in Ubuntu 23.10 on Acer laptop

Tags: power-management, battery, 23.10

I'd like to change the battery warning threshold from default values (i.e. 5%) to custom values. I've read in another question that I should edit the `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` and restart the upower service, and I did so, but that did not change the behavior (I still get the warning for critical power at 5%).

Simplified contents of `UPower.conf` file:

```
[UPower]

EnableWattsUpPro=false

NoPollBatteries=false

IgnoreLid=false

UsePercentageForPolicy=true

PercentageLow=30
PercentageCritical=20
PercentageAction=2

TimeLow=1200
TimeCritical=300
TimeAction=120
```

Not sure if this matters, but this is what I get from `systemctl list-unit-files` (grep for upower):

```
UNIT FILE                                      STATE           PRESET
upower.service                                 disabled        enabled
```

And this is from `systemctl list-units`:

```
UNIT                                   LOAD   ACTIVE     SUB       DESCRIPTION 
upower.service                         loaded active     running   Daemon for power management
```